# sorting arraylist using another arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a table with lat, long, location name.
I have calculated the nearest distance from the current location and added the distance in one arraylist and then sorted in ascending order.
Next i have added name in other arraylist.
Now i need to set the names in the order using the distance from other list.
How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using arrays too extensively here. If you have two or more pieces of related data, you should not put each piece into a separate array. Instead create a class to hold all the related data (lat, long, distance and name) and have an array (or some other collection that better meets your needs such as a SortedList) that holds instances of this class. The class could implement Comparable using distance as the measure and therefore allow sorting by distance.

Answer (score 1):

are your distances calculated by latitude, longtitude in that table? then why not using a map data structure?

it provides you the pair location-distance

Comment: if i put the values in the map then again i need to put them in to a list

Comment: i need to calculate distances using those lat, long and add the names in the list using the nearest distance

Answer (score 0):

Why not construct directly a [TreeMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeMap.html) with the distance as the key and the name as the value. That way they will always be kept sorted by distance.

Comment: TreeMap with distance as key is good idea, but what if there are 5 entries with same distance?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have some class that contains the latitude, longitude and location name.  You could put objects of this class into a `TreeSet`, where the comparator has the current location as constructor arguments, and calculates the distances to do the comparison.

Answer (score -1):

use [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29). You can dont even have to add the distance of each one from current in a separate array. just implement the comparator correctly.

use this after doing a `toArray()` on your `ArrayList`.

Comment: The point of the question was how to associate an array of names to an array of distances (that has been sorted).